# Module '"node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'

Tags: angular, typescript

> node_modules/@ionic/cloud-angular/dist/es5/index.d.ts
>
> Typescript Error
> Module '"/home/ritzylab/ionic-code-20-11/munshiji247-ionic/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';
```

Below you can find the version of my components:

**Ionic Framework: 3.9.2**

**Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.0**

**Angular Core: 7.0.4**

**Angular Compiler CLI: 7.0.4**

**Node: 11.2.0**

```
 "dependencies": {
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"@angular/common": "7.0.4",
"@angular/compiler": "7.0.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "7.0.4",
"@angular/core": "7.0.4",
"@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.19",
"@angular/forms": "7.0.4",
"@angular/http": "7.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "7.0.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "7.0.4",
"@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/base64": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/battery-status": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file-chooser": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file-opener": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/geolocation": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/http": "^4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/media": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/media-capture": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/network": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/transfer": "3.14.0",
"@ionic-native/video-capture-plus": "4.17.0",
"@ionic-native/video-player": "4.17.0",
"@ionic/cloud-angular": "0.12.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
"@types/cordova-plugin-battery-status": "1.2.3",
"@types/cordova-plugin-media": "3.0.0",
"@types/ionic": "3.19.0",
"@types/underscore": "1.8.9",
"angular2-signaturepad": "2.8.0",
"babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
"backo2": "1.0.2",
"component-bind": "1.0.0",
"cordova": "^8.1.2",
"cordova-android": "7.1.2",
"cordova-plugin-advanced-http": "2.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-battery-status": "2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.2.0",
"cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file-opener2": "2.0.19",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
"cordova-plugin-geolocation": "4.0.1",
"cordova-plugin-media": "^5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-media-capture": "3.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
"cordova-plugin-video-capture-plus": "1.0.0",
"cordova-plugin-video-player": "git+https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer.git",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
"cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine": "https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine.git",
"cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.5.1",
"engine.io-client": "3.3.1",
"font-awesome": "4.7.0",
"has-binary": "0.1.7",
"ionic": "^4.4.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
"ionic-image-loader": "6.3.2",
"ionic-img-viewer": "2.9.0",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
"ionicons": "4.4.7",
"isobject": "3.0.1",
"jquery": "3.3.1",
"lodash": "4.17.11",
"moment": "2.22.2",
"moment-timezone": "0.5.23",
"parseuri": "0.0.5",
"phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "8.0.0",
"phonegap-plugin-push": "2.2.3",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.12",
"rxjs": "6.3.3",
"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.3",
"setimmediate": "1.0.5",
"signature_pad": "3.0.0-beta.3",
"socket.io-client": "2.1.1",
"socket.io-parser": "3.3.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
"to-array": "0.1.4",
"underscore": "1.9.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.26"
```

Comment: try to solve by replacing OpaqueToken with InjectionToken :
```import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an incorrect version of the component flex-layout : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/flex-layout
Did you use it ? If yes, you can try that :

- delete "node-modules" directory,
- remove the @angular/flex-layout line in your package.json
- run command `npm i @angular/flex-layout`